# How to set velocity template character encoding with spring boot?

Tags: velocity, spring-boot

My templates have UTF-8 as encoding but the output from my web app is not correct. The problem is that velocity think that my templates have ISO-8859-1 as encoding since that is the output from this:

`System.out.println(ctx.getBean(VelocityEngine.class).getTemplate("index.html").getEncoding());`

It is possible to configure the output encoding by setting `spring.velocity.charSet=UTF-8` in application.properties, but my problem is not the output, it is the template encoding that is wrong. Velocity have this property `input.encoding` but I can not figure out how to set that with spring boot in an easy way. Do I have to recode my templates to iso?

Comment: When using tempting technologies and when trying to set properties not available through default Spring Boot properties there is a `spring.[template-engine].properties.*` that will work. So basically adding `spring.velocity.properties.input.encoding=UTF-8` to your `application.properties` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using templating technologies with Spring Boot and trying to set properties not available through default Spring Boot properties (like `spring.velocity.charSet`) there is a `spring.[template-engine].properties.*` that will work. See the [list of properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Basically adding `spring.velocity.properties.input.encoding=UTF-8` to your `application.properties` should do the trick.

```
spring.velocity.properties.input.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: For the record, Spring Boot 1.3 will set the `input.encoding` property based on `spring.velocity.charset`.